# Use jQuery .trigger() to fire two .bind() events

Tags: jquery, bind, eventtrigger

If I have a single event used like:

```
$("#total").keyup(function(){
    // Code here
});
```

I can trigger it like:

```
$("#total").trigger('keyup');
```

But if I have something like:

```
$("#total").bind("keyup change", function(e) {
    // Some logic here
});
```

is it possible to use `.trigger()` to fire the binded events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> [.trigger( eventType [, extraParameters ] )](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/): eventType is a string containing a JavaScript event type.

If you are using modern versions of jQuery, it's better to use on  instead of bind:

> As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.

So, you need:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#total").bind("keyup change", function(e) {
    console.log('event: ' + e.type);
  });
  $("#total").trigger('keyup').trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<button id="total">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: So I can chain multiple `.trigger()` calls. Neat! Thanks.